FCM Push Notification Limited for large TOPIC
Our project has already been updated to the latest version v1 of Firebase, and until a few days ago everything was running smoothly. For the last 3-4 days or so, submissions to TOPIC groups with more than 1000k registered members no longer work (neither from the api, nor from the Firebase console).
Submissions per topic only take place to TOPIC groups with under 1000k registered members.
From the console I don't see any limit quotas reached, I can't understand.

If you are trying to report a problem with Firebase services that are not related to your code, you should reach out to Firebase support for that.  We can't help if you're not showing specific code that doesn't work the way you expect.
